# SNR calculation from signal samples

Tags: snr

Is it possible to calculate the SNR from finite duration time-domain samples that contain the received signal, $y(t)$, where:

$$    y(t) = x(t) + n(t) $$
and $x(t) =$ transmitted signal, and $n(t) =$ AWGN noise

The signal $y(t)$ is complex baseband, filtered and resampled at Nyquist. The question here is, can the $\mathbb{E}\big[n(t)\big]$ be calculated from the finite number of samples that contain the energy of the signal?

note: this question addresses how to do it if you have periods of time where the signal is not transmitting: [SNR calculation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/42543/snr-calculation/42547#42547)

Comment: Do you have any assumptions about $x(t)$ or $n(t)$?

Comment: @Engineer not particularly? What did you have in mind?

Comment: For this kind of question, we need to use some a priori information in order to separate (at least partly) the signal from the noise. Ideally, we know the signal. If not, we may know it corresponds to a given finite alphabet, or that the signal bandwidth is limited.

Comment: Yes the signal bandwidth is limited. The following are known about the signal are: duration, bandwidth, start time of signal, and sample rate. No a-priori symbols/pilots/preamble to use for this question.

Comment: Do you know if $n(t)$ is zero mean noise?

Comment: @Engineer I'm not sure if it's zero mean b/c there is a receiver with AGC. That would change the mean of the noise figure right?